# DisplayAlerts for PPT links not working

Tags: vba, hyperlink, popup, powerpoint, alert

I'm running a VBA macro in PowerPoint, in which I open another PowerPoint document with several links in it.

I don't want the pop-up with the question to update these links to appear. So I included `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`. However this doesn't work: My macro still stops and shows the dialog, and I need to press Enter to be able to continue.

How do I fix this?

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Presentations.Open FileName:=stdRapport, ReadOnly:=msoFalse
ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks
```

Comment: identify the links and remove or update them

Comment: Hi Steve,

I've tryed the changes in the registry, but that didn't help. Any other ideas??

thx!

Comment: me how, links must be in the ppt, and need to be updated, but i don't want to see the dialog box with that question!

Answer (score 0):

.DisplayAlerts has never done much in PPT, unlike Excel et al.

You can theoretically disable hyperlink warnings via the registry. I've got a page here that gives the general outline and includes links to the relevant pages on MS for various Office versions:

Security warning message when clicking a hyperlink: "files might harm your computer"
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00587_Security_warning_message_when_clicking_a_hyperlink-_-files_might_harm_your_computer-.htm

I don't think there's any way of disabling hyperlink warnings on someone else's computer.